# is -negative margin or padding invalid CSS according to W3C?

Tags: css, w3c, w3c-validation

is -negative margin or padding are invalid CSS aaccording to W3C ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to  [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification - 8.4 Padding properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties), negative margin values are valid, negative padding values are not:

> Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative

Comment: Indeed. Negative margins are a key element of the Skidoo Layout, for example: http://webhost.bridgew.edu/etribou/layouts/skidoo/