# Is using negative values in CSS acceptable?

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of coding as well as CSS and this is the first page I have ever put together that required me to use negative values. I remember reading somewhere some time ago that it is best to stay away from using negative values. I am unsure why as I can't seem to locate that article any more.

I would appreciate your feedback on the use of negative values in my code below as well. I have avoided using any frameworks or the like so that I can grasp the concept of what CSS coding is all about.

Also I have used an internal stylesheet so that I can quickly amend my code rather than swapping between 2 different files. I would most certainly look at using an external stylesheet when developing a real world page. Secondly this is the first time I have used a reset stylesheet using import.

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Sample</title>


    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    @import url('http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css');

    body {

        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 1em;

    }

    #wrapper {

        /* background-color: #FAEBD7; */
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;

    }

    #innerwrapper {

        /* background-color: #CDC0B0; */
        overflow: auto;

    }

    #header {

        /* background-color: #8B8378; */

    }

    #logo {

        background-color: #000000;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 30px;

    }

    #topnav {

        /* background-color: #8B8970; */
        float: right;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 300px;
        text-align: right;


    }

    #status {

        /* background-color: #808080; */
        width: 100px;
        position: relative;
        top: -80px;
        left: 800px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #topnav ul {

        word-spacing: 5px;

    }

    #topnav ul li {

        display: inline;

    }

    #separator {

        border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
        margin-top: 20px;

    }

    #content {

        /* background-color: #68838B; */
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 60px;

    }

    #innercontent {

        /* background-color: #778899; */
        float: left;
        width: 600px;

    }

    #rightcol {

        /* background-color: #CDCDB4; */
        float: right;
        width: 300px;

    }

    #rightcol p + p {

        margin-top: 1em;

    }

    #footer {

        /* background-color: #CDB7B5; */
        margin-top: 20px;

    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="innerwrapper">
            <div id="header">

                <div id="logo">logo</div>

                <div id="topnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>about</li>
                        <li>browse</li>
                        <li>join</li>

                        <li>faq</li>
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="status">login</div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="separator"></div>


        <div id="content">
            <div id="innercontent">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at elementum neque vestibulum sollicitudin semper neque, vitae metus. Nibh ligula mi. Faucibus rutrum elit turpis, nec congue quam ipsum felis neque et, wisi amet, architecto eros congue. Maecenas suspendisse tellus arcu eget pharetra, rhoncus aenean sapien morbi nec arcu, vivamus aliquet lorem amet at, vestibulum purus sociis varius id. Imperdiet id magnis turpis beatae aliquet, vestibulum dolor nec eget eu cras lobortis, vel rerum, risus sed et, libero et non eros commodo. Taciti eu leo sollicitudin malesuada, nibh duis amet aenean, odio aptent ultrices. Tristique morbi nunc ullamcorper ut curabitur. Et a in ut sem varius, sem rutrum vehicula sem sed, at diam amet erat vel. Et sit in ante felis vitae sit.

                Quam eget sed elit natoque velit, enim mauris mauris urna, integer amet tellus illo ipsum, dolor fermentum cursus enim mollis tristique porttitor. Non dignissim. Sit ligula leo tincidunt, justo ut ut placerat quisque non, risus nonummy. Ultrices mauris congue aliquam aliquam felis, at placerat, amet vestibulum dictumst pellentesque iaculis risus. Sem sed impedit nullam ultrices lorem aliquam, nulla tellus consequatur in ornare magna. Viverra amet pede in in ornare eu, id arcu. Justo mus suspendisse praesent et, amet mattis convallis ullamcorper felis, fermentum nibh at ac, ullamcorper ipsum auctor et maecenas, aliquam molestiae in qui. Massa elit suspendisse penatibus molestie libero dolor, non leo vitae, sollicitudin a, platea tristique iaculis, tortor augue non est. Ante rutrum quis pellentesque lacinia convallis non, vestibulum nibh nunc luctus nibh a, in amet, iaculis dui ornare pede laoreet eu. Cursus integer vehicula quis, justo eget purus mattis donec vestibulum nunc, nunc vel eros lectus.
            </div>


            <div id="rightcol">
                <p>paragraph1</p>
                <p>paragraph2</p>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div id="footer">footer</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT - Updated code as per wdm's suggestion**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Sample</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    @import url('http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css');

    body {

        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 1em;

    }

    #wrapper {

        /* background-color: #FAEBD7; */
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;

    }

    #innerwrapper {

        /* background-color: #CDC0B0; */
        overflow: auto;

    }

    #header {

        /* background-color: #8B8378; */

    }

    #logo {

        background-color: #000000;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 30px;

    }

    #status {

        /* background-color: #808080; */
        position: relative;
        top: -85px;
        left: 780px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;

    }

    #topnav {

        /* background-color: #8B8970; */
        float: right;
        width: 300px;
        margin-top: -70px;
        text-align: right;


    }

    #topnav ul {

        word-spacing: 5px;

    }

    #topnav ul li {

        display: inline;

    }

    #separator {

        border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
        margin-top: 20px;

    }

    #content {

        /* background-color: #68838B; */
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 60px;

    }

    #innercontent {

        /* background-color: #778899; */
        float: left;
        width: 600px;

    }

    #rightcol {

        /* background-color: #CDCDB4; */
        float: right;
        width: 300px;

    }

    #rightcol p + p {

        margin-top: 1em;

    }

    #footer {

        /* background-color: #CDB7B5; */
        margin-top: 20px;

    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="innerwrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo">logo</div>

                <div id="status">Logged in</div>

                <div id="topnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>about</li>
                        <li>browse</li>
                        <li>join</li>
                        <li>faq</li>
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="separator"></div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="innercontent">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at elementum neque vestibulum sollicitudin semper neque, vitae metus. Nibh ligula mi. Faucibus rutrum elit turpis, nec congue quam ipsum felis neque et, wisi amet, architecto eros congue. Maecenas suspendisse tellus arcu eget pharetra, rhoncus aenean sapien morbi nec arcu, vivamus aliquet lorem amet at, vestibulum purus sociis varius id. Imperdiet id magnis turpis beatae aliquet, vestibulum dolor nec eget eu cras lobortis, vel rerum, risus sed et, libero et non eros commodo. Taciti eu leo sollicitudin malesuada, nibh duis amet aenean, odio aptent ultrices. Tristique morbi nunc ullamcorper ut curabitur. Et a in ut sem varius, sem rutrum vehicula sem sed, at diam amet erat vel. Et sit in ante felis vitae sit.

                Quam eget sed elit natoque velit, enim mauris mauris urna, integer amet tellus illo ipsum, dolor fermentum cursus enim mollis tristique porttitor. Non dignissim. Sit ligula leo tincidunt, justo ut ut placerat quisque non, risus nonummy. Ultrices mauris congue aliquam aliquam felis, at placerat, amet vestibulum dictumst pellentesque iaculis risus. Sem sed impedit nullam ultrices lorem aliquam, nulla tellus consequatur in ornare magna. Viverra amet pede in in ornare eu, id arcu. Justo mus suspendisse praesent et, amet mattis convallis ullamcorper felis, fermentum nibh at ac, ullamcorper ipsum auctor et maecenas, aliquam molestiae in qui. Massa elit suspendisse penatibus molestie libero dolor, non leo vitae, sollicitudin a, platea tristique iaculis, tortor augue non est. Ante rutrum quis pellentesque lacinia convallis non, vestibulum nibh nunc luctus nibh a, in amet, iaculis dui ornare pede laoreet eu. Cursus integer vehicula quis, justo eget purus mattis donec vestibulum nunc, nunc vel eros lectus.
            </div>

            <div id="rightcol">
                <p>paragraph 1</p>
                <p>paragraph 2</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623163/is-negative-margin-or-padding-invalid-css-according-to-w3c?

Comment: Negative values are perfectly acceptable however I would use them sparingly. They are definitely useful in certain situations.

Comment: @wdm - What situations are they useful for? Is my use of a negative value acceptable?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - Not sure why you deleted your answer and my question regarding your answer but my question is not a duplicate considering it is regarding the attribute position and whether negative values are acceptable. This the question I posed to you. Is the property position considered padding? The answer to your question in the link you posted is specifically related to padding and margin.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - my question is not deleted by someone else and I never said that your question is duplicate. I just read your title "Is using negative values in CSS acceptable?" and I just wanted to share with you that negative values are acceptable in CSS except for padding.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Your markup should follow the visual flow of your page. I wouldn't use a negative margin in the way you are. One common use is when overlaying elements. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/jwBzv/

Comment: @wdm - Thanks. When you say `visual flow` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - You misunderstood me. You first comment states that either my question is a duplicate or either yours is a duplicate. Anyhoo  no biggie. I just wanted to clarify that the question was regarding the `position` property rather than `padding`.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey From what I can see you're using the negative margin to move an element above another element when you should write the HTML to reflect that first and then use CSS to fine tune it.

Comment: @wdm - Do you mean that the div element `<div id="status">login</div>
` should appear the `topnav` div element?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Yes I would put it above the topnav.

Comment: @wdm - Thanks. I did start off with that however found it quicker to implement my code sample. I'll amend the code and will post the update as an edit and would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @wdm - I have updated the code. Please let know if it is the right way of doing it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I added an answer below with a demo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me consolidate my comments into an answer here.

First: Negative values are perfectly acceptable however I would use them sparingly. They are definitely useful in certain situations

HTML markup should follow the visual flow of your page. I wouldn't use a negative margin in the way you originally intended. One common use is when overlaying elements. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/jwBzv

How would I fix your top menu code? I would wrap `#status` and your `UL` within `#topnav` like this...

```
<div id="topnav">
  <div id="status">Logged in</div>
    <ul>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>browse</li>
      <li>join</li>
      <li>faq</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And use something along these lines for the CSS...

```
#topnav {
    float: right;
}
#topnav #status {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#topnav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/RwEWN/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Why didn't I think of that? That definitely helped me to think the way I should code. I am however hoping you can elaborate on when negative values are useful and when I should use them?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I only tend to use negative margins when necessary. I think it's better to avoid using them until you run into a problem where negative margins are the only reasonable solution. That's how I think about it at least. Shoot for coding elegance over convenience.

Answer (score 6):

Negative values can be very powerful when used correctly. There is no problem with using negative values.

Comment: Thanks. Is the use of a negative value in my example appropriate? Also in what other situations are they acceptable?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: It's fine. It's basically always acceptable to use negative values. Don't worry about this.

Comment: @Marcin - Based on the guidelines set out by W3C, it seems it is not acceptable to use negative values for padding.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: In reality it's probably fine, but as with any CSS, you would be well advised to test across browsers. There are obviously other cases where it's probably not going to be fine, like for text-height. The key is to use your discretion, and not to worry about this overly.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Have you considered negative margins instead of padding? That will probably do what you want, and is explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from using negative margins as they can be confusing and difficult to understand, but using negative values for positioning (like what you have done) is common and totally acceptable!

You cannot use negative values for padding.

Comment: Thanks. When you say that `they can be confusing and difficult to understand`, what do you mean exactly? So I take it that the properties `position`, `margin` and `padding` are unique to each other i.e. `position` is not the same as `margin` or `padding`?

Comment: when you revisit the code a few weeks/months/years from now, it may be difficult to see why you used negative margins and how they make your elements interact with each other. negative margins *are* valid, but I think there is often a better, *cleaner* way to accomplish the same thing. if you do use them, remember to comment your code to explain what you were thinking when you wrote it.  and yes, `position`, `margin`, and `padding` are all different, independent things.

Comment: Thanks. That is a helpful tip for commenting my code on why I did it.

Answer (score 0):

If it gives you the result you're looking for, sure, there's no problem with negative values. There's not really anything inherently bad about them. They can make positioning things much easier.

Comment: Thanks. Although they make positioning easier, is it recommended or discouraged? If the latter why is that?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: there's no be-all, end-all rule against it, and I've never heard of it being discouraged. If you can find convincing evidence arguing otherwise, please share, but in the meantime, I will continue to use them where I see necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Negative values are acceptable in CSS with most of properties but some properties are there in CSS which don't accept negative values, For example : Padding

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, to maximise your chance of getting your answer **[accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** and **[upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.