# Place div on the bottom of another div

Tags: css

I've tried many things but i can not figure out how to put `div2` on the bottom of the `div1` I want top part of `div2` to be inside of the `div1` bottom side

Like this [image]

Any suggestions please?

https://jsfiddle.net/njwq14vu/13/

Comment: You could do that with `margin-top:-20px;`

Comment: But using negative values is not considered to be the recommended way of handling CSS so maybe position: absolute in the answers below may work more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```css
.div1 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  top: -10px;
  position: relative;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">Helo</div>
<div class="div2">Helo1</div>
</div>
```

**What changed:**

- `.div2` has `top` property set to `-10px`, in order to show it 10 pixels before than first;
- `.div2` has also `position` property set to `relative`, that allow the HTML element to override his design default behaviour (`static`).

Comment: You dont even realize how much you've saved me lol,I all accept your answer in few minutes

Comment: Not a problem, I'm here to help, however I just added an explanation in order to make this solution the clearest as possible :)

Comment: @xKobalt Its **never a good idea** and is NOT rec-emended  to use negative (-) values in CSS - see my answer

Comment: @NikaRoffy you probably better off NOT using negative values - its not a good practice. See my asnwer

Comment: Well, I don't know why you're saying that's not a good practice, since I searched [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134231/is-using-negative-values-in-css-acceptable) and it seems that negative values are accepted and also needed in some cases

Comment: @xKobalt if you read closely - it depend on certain situation - and in this question it not rec-emended at all. it can be achieved easily with correct position value. there are only divs we need to play with.

Comment: I also looked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134231/is-using-negative-values-in-css-acceptable#6134250/), its comments and more answers before posting that comment... The OP in that question had the same kind of problem after all

Answer (score 3):

try this instead,
add `relative` positioning to container div

```
.container{
      position:relative;
}
```

and `absolute` positioning to div2

```
.div2{
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:15px;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
}

.div2 {
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:120px;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:15px;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question (div2 to be inside of the div1), I unedrstand you want to overlap..
[Is this the kind ouf Output you are looking for?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBa3d.png)

You can use Position: Absolute; in your css code to achieve this.

CSS below:

```
.div1 {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:120px;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:120px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can operate left and right attributes as desired for your design.

```css
.container{
position: relative;
}
.div1 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">Helo</div>
<div class="div2">Helo1</div>
```

Comment: Nice help out and very complete. However, maybe you could elaborate on why this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position absolute` on your `div2` with `left` and `top` to make sure it stays on top of `div1`

**Live Demo:**

```css
.div1 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5em;
  left: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Helo</div>
  <div class="div2">Helo1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Idk how to explain i will try to draw it and update the post

Comment: @NikaRoffy See my answer now. perfectly working now :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping you answer is working perfectly, but making it absolute without positioning parent may create a problem.

Comment: @PranavRustagi Thank you Pranav. but i respectfully disagree. Since in this example container is always `relative`.

Comment: I don't think it's written in code, or in question...About `.container` being positioned. :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thank you for the time and solution,But in my case `position:absolute` is working bad for me,everything else is fine

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this helps you. I have added two attributes to `.div2` class keeping your code intact.

```css
.div1 {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:120px;
}

.div2 {
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:120px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">Helo</div>
<div class="div2">Helo1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its **never a good idea** and is NOT rec-emended to use negative (-) values in CSS - see my answer

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advise @AlwaysHelping, and yes I agree with it that negative values should be kept as a last option while handling styles with CSS. Check your answer and added to my knowledge-base the positive handling of this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div in another div, and then use flex's 'order' property like so

```css
.example {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.example > .a {order: 3; } /* Will be displayed third  */
.example > .b {order: 2; } /* Will be displayed second */
.example > .c {order: 1; } /* Will be displayed first  */
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <div class="a">First</div>
    <div class="b">Second</div>
    <div class="c">Third</div>
</div>
```