# Place a div along border edge of div

Tags: html, css, css-position

In my web application, I wanted to place a small div along border edge of another div like this:

[image: Div along the border of another div]

This is my code:

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black; height:1em; width:10em;">
<div style="border:1px solid black; display:inline-block; height:10em; 
width:10em;"> Along edge </div>
 </div>
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Post the code you've tried to get more help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following way you can do it. Make main div `position:relative` and along edge div `position:absolute` to main div. And give `top` and `right` to sub div.

```css
.main{
    border:2px solid;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    top:50px;
}
.sub{
    border:1px solid;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:-10px;
    z-index:99;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    Main Div
    <div class="sub">
        along edge
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have an one doubt.. as w3c standards, css value is not behave as minus right?..thanks..

Comment: @saina You should refer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623163/is-negative-margin-or-padding-invalid-css-according-to-w3c

Comment: okay.. then what about for others like top,bottom, left and right.. i just know the details..thanks..

Comment: top, bottom, left and right with negative is allowed.

Comment: html5 custom tags? means?

Comment: Sorry i have not idea about that thing.

Answer (score 2):

put css like this

```
.main-div
{
 position:relative;
}
.along-edge
{
 position:absolute;
 right:50px;
 top:-20px;
 z-index:1;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/xne9z66z/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="Main">
    <div id="Edge"></div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#Main{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#Edge{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:absolute;
    top:-25px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/emfm832s/)

Comment: may i know, how to hide the line inside of along edge in your demo? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nest the smaller div inside the main div.

```
.along-edge {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -10px;
z-index: 1;
}
```